# Element of a quotient group that equals to 0

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, quotient-group

I may be a bit confused but somehow I do not see why the following holds:

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal. Then we have the quotient $R/I$. Let $a+I \in R/I$.

Why does it hold that if $a+I = 0 \implies a \in I$? It makes sense to me if think of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. But not in this case, however. How would the formal proof look like? Or is a proof not even necessary and it follows by definition?

**Possible explanation**

Let's consider $0+I$ which is the set $\{0 + i | \forall i \in I\}=I$, right?

So, I have that $a + I = I$. But this means that $\{a + i | \forall i \in I\} = I$ and since $0 \in I$ we have that $a+0 \in I$ and this is $a \in I$. Is this argumentation correct?

Comment: It's automatic by equality of cosets:  $a+I = 0+I$ implies that $a-0 \in I$.

Comment: In $R/I$ the zero element is $I$ so that $a+I=0$ stands for $a+I=I$. This is equivalent with $a\in I$.

Comment: Ideals are the kernel of the quotient map by construction. If $a+I=0$ it's in the kernel of that map and so must be in the kernel itself.

Comment: I added a possible explanation. Is that what you meant?

Comment: So this is about rings and an ideal; of course the quotient as a ring is the same set as the quotient as a group, but surely the subject line and the tags should reflect that this is, essentially, about rings, not groups.